# "Us Students" Or "We Students"

Tags: phrase-choice

> We students who had not studied were at a disadvantage.

Or

> Us students who had not studied were at a disadvantage.

Answer (score 3):

"We students" is correct. The students are the subject of the verb, so you should use the subject form of the pronoun.

If the students were the object of the verb, you would use "us". For example, "The teacher yelled at us students who had not studied."

If you generally have a "feel" for pronouns: Use the same pronoun that you would use if the modifying noun was not there. You wouldn't say "Us who had not studied ..." You would say "We who had not studied ..." (But if that doesn't help, go back to the subject/object rule.)